# How to Set Layout like TitleWindow or BackButton on MapView

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-manifest

I have made an application in which I am getting the direction by parse the ready made URL to the `Google MapView`. Now I want to set the `Back Button` and the my own header On the top of the layout.
How could it be possible? Please help me. . . 
My code is as below:

```
StringBuffer mapUrl = new StringBuffer();
```

// onCreate Method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapUrl.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?");
    mapUrl.append("saddr="+21.22794190505816+","+72.8173828125);
    mapUrl.append("&daddr="+23.039297747769726+","+72.59765);

    System.out.println("MapUrl: "+mapUrl.toString());

    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(mapUrl.toString()));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Now how could be possible to set the `Back Button` and `Title` on the `MapDirection Page`.
Please help me. . .

Answer (score 0):

I have already answer this questions please check this

[How to Set Layout with Mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699577/how-to-set-layout-with-mapview/5700067#5700067)

if you find it as useful please mark it as an answer

Best Regards,
Anup

Comment: Budy, Still u Don't Understand the Problem. . .

Comment: Just Run My Code in by Making Small application then u got the reality that what happend. . . Your answer cant seen the Layout on the Direction page and i m loading the direction by ready made url by pasing to the New Intent.. . .

Comment: ok so you are using GoogleMap native app provided already on the device to invoke your URL is it so please confirm.

Comment: So How it's Possible to Set the Header title and the Back Button in that Direction Page. . . ?

Comment: Ithin kyou can use a FrameLayout in order to something on Title & on th bottom, and embedd you mapactivity in that.